# Session not created exception

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm trying to execute multiple class into the XML file , into afterclass annotation I implemented driver.close to close browser after execution but the thing is after execution of my first class in the XML file, the next class are not executing ..I'm getting error of session not created I could not able to execute completely because of this issue
1 st class in the XML file executed completed and upcoming class are skipped. @ Before test browser setup is implemented
My chrome browser version and exe version are the same

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to close the session in @AfterClass annotation, once first class execution completed, it will close the session before 2nd class execution starts. There are 2 solutions for this:

1. If your requirement is to close the session for every @Test class: In this case, include launchBrowser() code inside @BeforeClass annotation and close browser code in @AfterClass. By this way, browser will be launched for every Test class via @BeforeClass and closed via @AfterClass.
2. If your requirement is to do not close the session for all Tests: In this case, include browser launch code in @BeforeTest annotation and close the browser in resective @AfterTest annotation
3. In case your xml have more than one test and you do not need to close the session for all the tests, include browser launch code in @BeforeSuite and close the session via @AfterSuite.